# maggicsuggest 'selectionchange' get the id of the added / deleted item

Tags: jquery, magicsuggest

How can i get id of just added / deleted item? I need to update the database after adding or removing an item.

```
$(ms).on('selectionchange', function(event, combo, selection){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the diff from the event parameters.

What you can do:

1: It's an open-source project so you can open a feature request. Better yet, you can implement it yourself and create a pull request. It should be something like this:

```
$(ms).on('selectionchange', function(event, combo, selection, diff){
     // diff is an array of json objects that were added / removed    
});
```

2: You can track the current selection and then manually do the diff yourself:

```
$(ms).on('selectionchange', function(event, combo, selection, diff){
     if(this.cursel){
         // check diff b/w selection and this.cursel
     }
     this.cursel = selection;   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do:

```js
var diffArray = [];

$(ms).on('selectionchange', function(e, m, records) {

  var l = records.length;
  var a1 = a2 = [];
  var action = "add";

  if (l > diffArray.length) {
    a1 = records;
    a2 = diffArray;

  } else {
    a1 = diffArray;
    a2 = records;
    var action = "remove";
  }

  var difference = $.grep(a1, function(el) {
    return $.inArray(el, a2) == -1;
  });
  
  diffArray = records.slice();
  
  console.log(action);
  console.log(difference);
  

});
```